# how to fix object "undefined"

Tags: javascript, object

Please tell me how to fix, where answer comes with "object undefined".

```
var dog = {
name : "Fido",
weight : 20.2,
age : 4,
breed : "mixed",
activity : "fetch balls"
};
var bark;
if (dog.weight > 20) {
bark = "WOOF WOOF";
} else {
bark = "woof woof";
}

var speak = dog.name + " says " + dog.bark + " when he wants to " +     dog.activity;
console.log(speak);
```

Comment: The last part should read as :  var speak = dog.name + " says " + dog.bark + " when he wants to " + dog.activity;  console.log (speak);  ---- ---- the dog.bark returns with "undefined".

Comment: replace `dog.bark` with `bark`

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response, kukkuz.

Comment: `dog` doesn't have a `bark` property. Either add it or access the variable `bark` instead. Why are you trying to access `dog.bark` if such a property doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `bark = "..."`, if you want to set it as a property of `dog` object, set it as:

```
dog.bark = "WOOF WOOF";
```

```js
var dog = {
  name: "Fido",
  weight: 20.2,
  age: 4,
  breed: "mixed",
  activity: "fetch balls"
};

if (dog.weight > 20) {
  dog.bark = "WOOF WOOF";
} else {
  dog.bark = "woof woof";
}

var speak = dog.name + " says " + dog.bark + " when he wants to " + dog.activity;
console.log(speak);
```